# backbone.js updating model defaults

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I update the defaults object of a Model?

For example, let's say I have Box object modelled below. It has a default "Colour" attribute set to "#FFF".

Once the user starts interacting with the server, at some point the server passes back a new default colour #000. I want all new boxes instantiated from that point onwards to default to a colour attribute of #000.

As an aside, assuming I perform this update, since the defaults is passed by reference, all existing boxes will also have their defaults updated. Is this correct?

```js
var Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "Colour"  : "#FFF"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default can be changed easily with

```
Box.prototype.defaults.Colour = '#000'
```

And when you change this, the boxes that have already been created will have, deep in their prototype chain, a new value

```
myBox.__proto__.constructor.prototype.defaults.Colour === '#000'
```

but that won't matter and it won't change the value that comes from `myBox.get('Colour')` because the defaults get copied to`myBox.attributes` at instantiation.  To change existing boxes, you'd have to use `myBox.set({'Colour': '#000'})` or `myBox.attributes.Colour = '#000'`.

(I hope I interpreted your question correctly)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your Colour attribute is not really a state of your model that is saved.  It may be more appropriate to have it be a class property.  So you might do this:

```
var Box = Backbone.Model.extend({

  // Instance properties here.

}, {

  colour: '#FFF'

});
```

and then if you need to use this property, you reference it as:

```
Box.colour
```

and if you need to change it, you need only do:

```
Box.colour = #000;
```

This approach may or may not be appropriate to your app as there could be a reason why it needs to be an instance property.  But it seems like its a property of the class more than a class' instances.

Comment: Thanks @Bill I was looking specifically for the Box.prototype.defaults._attribute_ technique, but this discussion about instance vs class properties is useful too.